# How can I pass useQuery variable from component prop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, frontend, apollo

I have this query :

```
const GET_ANALYTICS = gql`
  query($courseId: String) {
    getStudentsAnalytics(courseId: $courseId) {
        totalStudents,
        studentsNotStartedCoursesYetPercentage,
        studentsFinishedCoursesPercentage,
        studentsInProgressCoursesPercentage,
        studentsCompletedQuizzesPercentage,
        studentsFailedQuizzesPercentage,
        studentsInProgressQuizzesPercentage
    }
}
`
```

and in the code am trying to pass variable from component prop:

```
const AnalyticsStatistic = (courseId: string) => {

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ANALYTICS){
   variables: {courseId},
 }
```

for red underlined param courseId am getting these errors:'courseId' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
Duplicate identifier 'courseId'.ts(2300)

and for inside variable: {courseId} am getting these errors:Duplicate identifier 'courseId'.ts(2300)
Binding element 'courseId' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

[for inside courseId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Yqmv.png)

[for outside courseId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY4xH.png)

[problems in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VuHf.png)

Comment: add your GET_ANALYTICS query code. and try `courseId` only and not an object

Comment: I have posted the answer by assuming a query for `GET_ANALYTICS` if that solves your issue, please mark it as answered

Comment: make the `courseId` to string beacuse teh query is expecting it be only a string

Comment: if it worked please upvote and mark it as answered :)

Comment: I need reputation for that but I checked it solved <33

Comment: @losebOne no problem !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `GET_ANALYTICS` query is like this, so you don't have to pass the courseId inside an object check the code below

```
const GET_ANALYTICS = gql`
  query($courseId: String) {
    getStudentsAnalytics(courseId: $courseId) {
        ....
    }
}
`
```

the corresponding useQuery hook should be used like this and make the courseId argument to **string** instead of **any** because query is expecting a string

```
const AnalyticsStatistic = (courseId: string) => {
                                           //? FIX 
 const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ANALYTICS,{
  variables: {courseId},
})
```

if you are getting unused variable, then add this inside `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  }
}
```

Comment: not yet, i've also added screenshots for my problem can you please check them ?

Comment: I have updated my answer try setting those flags inside tsconfig.json

Comment: is it set to false? if it is true then change it to false

Comment: can you also add the image of error which is displayed in the console after running the application ?

Comment: I added , can you please check that ?

Comment: mate, check the useQuery hook, it is `useQuery(GET_ANALYTICS, {variables:{courseId})` not `useQuery(GET_ANALYTICS), {variables:{courseId}`, I have updated my answer

Comment: god bless you mate <33 sometimes we need to go get some rest and then return to code. thanks for attention